# Chrome auto fill not saving form data

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, autocomplete

I created a form and when I submitted it, it was not saving data in chrome autofill database. I inspected html page of amazon.com and I have come up with a bare minimum form that helps saving data in auto fill database. Following is the code.

```
<BODY>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">

<div class="col-lg-6">

          <div >
            <label for="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressLine1"  >First Nadme</label>
            <input  name="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressLine1"  id="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressLine1"  maxlength="30"  type="text">
          </div>

          <div >
            <label >Lastaaa </label>
            <input  id="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressCity" maxlength="30"  type="text">
          </div>

          <div >
            <label >username</label>
            <input  id="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressStateOrRegion"  maxlength="150" type="text" >
          </div>

          <div >
            <label >dfkdfk</label>
            <input  id="address-ui-widgets-enterAddressPostalCode"  maxlength="254"  type="text">
          </div>


        </div>

      </div> <!-- panel-body -->

      <div class="panel-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Register">
      </div> <!-- panel-footer -->
    </div> <!-- panel -->
  </form>
</BODY>
```

I have just added random labels. The only thing that i am not getting is that if I change name of any id then auto fill does not save any data. I  am unable to get the logic.

Comment: I have a similar issue